# filter function not working in an Array using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise, nodes

I am trying to filter out empty array but its not happening

- I was trying to compare value which are present inside my database and fileName
- I tried `arr.filter(Boolean);`
- even i tried `arr.filter((item)=>item)`

PS: fileName is not an array value so I converted it into array.

```
function checkDoc(data, childProduct, fileName, pathName, req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Document.findAll({
      raw: true,
      where: {
        product_id: childProduct.id,
      },
    })
      .then((productDoc) => {
        if (productDoc.length === 0) {
          return resolve(addDocument(data, childProduct, fileName, pathName));
        } else {
          let fileArray = [];
          fileArray.push(fileName);
          productDoc.forEach((singleProduct) => {
            let productValue = singleProduct.name;
            let unMatchedValues = fileArray.filter((value) =>
              productValue.includes(value)
            );
            let removedBoolean = unMatchedValues.filter((item) => item);
            console.log("Document Name: ", removedBoolean);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return reject("Can't be added please try again :) " + err);
      });
  });
}
```

```
fileName:
ABC
PQR
XYZ
Installation and Configuration
Java
Node Js
```

where as in singleProduct.name it contain

```
[ABC]
[PQR]
[Installation and Configuration]
[XYZ]
```

attached Output Image :

[image]

Expected OutPut:

```
matchedValue:
[`document name: ABC`]
[`document name: PQR`]
[`document name: Installation and configuration`]
[`document name: XYZ`]
```

```
unmatchedValue:
['Java']
[`Node Js`]
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. what is the expected output?

Comment: hi @thedude i have updated my question please have a look :)

Comment: what is `fileName` in this example run?

Comment: You should just do some debugging here. Inspect or log the various values at each point in the code and you'll soon see what's going wrong. If you haven't used filter before, then you should read a basic intro to filter and try out a few tests in the Node REPL.

Comment: Hello @jarmod in my previous function i have used filter but dont know why its not working here :)

Comment: Hello @thedude i have added `fileName` and `singleProduct.name` Value in code :)

Comment: Inside the `forEach()` you have an unconditional `console.log()` line. That will always log something, regardless of what that something is. If you want to skip elements, use `filter()` before the `forEach()`, or simply use an `if` in front of `console.log()`

Comment: I am comparing `fileName` which is converted into `fileArray`
* so my two array `fileArray` and `singleProduct.name` can be compared and difference and easily extracted @jarmod

Comment: At that point, you only have two filenames, both simple strings: `singleProduct.name` and `fileName`. You can just compare them directly. Why jump through hoops by converting one to a single-element array and then using filter?

Comment: so how can i compare them directly any solution @jarmod ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to filter an array of objects to remove those with empty names, here's an example:

```js
const team = [
  { name: 'max', age: 21 },
  { name: '', age: 19 },
  { name: 'james', age: 33 },
  { name: '', age: 30 },
];

// Log the entire team
console.log('Team:', team);

// Log only those team members with names
console.log('Team with names:', team.filter(x => x.name));

// Log only the names
console.log('Names:', team.filter(x => x.name).map(x => x.name));
```